# number of function $f$ from $f:\mathbb{A}\rightarrow \mathbb{A}$ and satisfying $f(f(x))=x$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Let $A=\{1,2,3,4\}\;,$ Then total number of function $f$ from $f:\mathbb{A}\rightarrow \mathbb{A}$
>
> and satisfying $f(f(x))=x$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ If $f(x)=x\;,$ Then $f(f(x))=x.$ So there are  $4$ possibilities,

Like $(f(1)=1,f(2)=2,f(3)=3,f(4)=4)$

Now How can I calculate other possibilities, Help Required, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If will equal the number of partitions of set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ having the property that their elements have cardinality $1$ or $2$.

E.g. partition $\{\{1\},\{2,3\},\{4\}\}$ represents the function prescribed by:

- $1\mapsto1$
- $2\mapsto3$ and $3\mapsto2$
- $4\mapsto4$

Answer (score 1):

## (This answer is wrong, because I did not consider the case where $f(x)=x$ for certain $x$. Correct answer in the comments!)

Note that $f$ must be bijective (thus surjective and injective). So it suffices to look at the permutations of $\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Also $f$ must be its own inverse, so it must satisfy a permutation of the form $(a,b)(c,d)$ in disjoint cycle notation.

Choosing $a$ gives 4 possibilities. Choosing $b$ gives 3 possibilities. You're  counting these double, since $(a,b) = (b,a)$. Now $c$ and $d$ leaves only one possibility. This means there are $\frac{4\cdot 3}{2} = 6$ possible functions $f$.

Comment: Actually there are 3: (1,2)(3,4),(1,3)(2,4),(1,4)(2,3). You count them twice.

Comment: $10$ possibilities? $f\in \{e, (12), (13), (14), (23), (24), (34), (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}\subseteq S_4$.

Comment: @bfhaha Yes, this looks right.

Comment: For any $x\in \Bbb{A}$, $x=f(f(x))\in \text{im }f$, so $f$ is onto.
Since the number of elements of the finite domain is the same as the codomain, $f$ is one-to-one.

Comment: You're correct @bfhaha ! I forgot to take $f(x)=x$ in consideration for some $x$. I've referred to your solution!

Comment: @bfhaha Correct. Moreover $f$ would also one-to-one without finiteness and/or equality of domain and codomain: $f(x)=f(y)\implies x=f(f(x))=f(f(y))=y$. Actually $f$ is its own inverse and a function is bijective if and only if it is invertible.